# Include <headers.h> installed in non standard location

Tags: c++11, bazel

I'm currently working with a third party library, which has headers declared using angular brackets, like a standard library :

```
#include <header.h>
```

However, these headers are installed in a non standard place, something like `/opt/company/software/version/part_software/include`

With a more traditional builder like MAKE, I can just use CXXFLAGS to indicate to g++ to look in this folder too for libraries, which finally comes down to pass a `-I/opt/company/software/version/part_software/include` option to g++.

When trying to do the same thing in bazel, using `copts = [ "-I/opt/company/software/version/part_software/include" ]`, I get a "`path outside of the execution root`" error.

It's my understanding that bazel don't like the place where the lib is installed because the build needs to be reproducible, and including a library located outside the execution root violate this constraint.

A ugly hack I've come with is to create symbolic link of the headers in `/usr/local/include`, and use `copts = [ "-I/usr/local/include" ]` in the bazel build. However, I find this approach very hacky, and **I'd like to find a more bazely approach to the problem.**

---

**Note :** I can't install the program during the bazel build, as it uses a closed installer on which I have no control over. This installer can't be run in the bazel's sandboxed environment, as it needs to write on certain paths not accessible within the environment.

Comment: I'm sure there are build options that will fix it, but I don't know bazel :-). If all else fails, could you add a symlink from your project folder to the installed folder? Or from somewhere else where you are able to set up paths.

Comment: I don't know `bazel`, but looking on the docs website there is something about 3rd part code: https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/bazel-and-cpp.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, it turns out that the *bazelesque* way of including a third part library is simply to create package encapsulating the library.

Thanks to this useful [discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/bazel-discuss/B2ZZIr1AeZM/TnEMdi5LBAAJ), I've managed to create a package with my third party library.

First we need a BUILD file, here named `package_name.BUILD`

```
package(
    default_visibility = ["//visibility:public"]
)

cc_library(
    name = "third_party_lib_name", #name to reference the third party library in other BUILD files
    srcs = [
        "external/soft/lib/some_lib.so", #.so files to include in the lib
        "software/lib/os/arch/lib_some_plugin.so",
    ],
    hdrs = glob([ # the glob takes all the headers needed
        "software/include/**/*.h",
        "software/include/**/*.hpp",
    ]), 
    includes = ["software/include/"], # Specify which files are included when we use the library
)
```

Now we need to reference the lib a a submodule in the WORKSPACE file :

```
  new_local_repository(
      name = "package_name",
      path = "opt/company/software/version",
      # build_file: path to the BUILD file, here in the same directory that the main WORKSPACE one
      build_file = __workspace_dir__ + "/package_name.BUILD", 
      )
```

Now, instead of using `copt` to references the needed headers, I'm just adding a line to the deps of the `cc_rule` when needed, e.g :

```
cc_library(
    name="some_internal_lib",
    srcs = ["some_internal_lib.cc"],
    deps = [
         "@package_name//:third_party_lib_name", #referencing the third party lib
           ],
)
```